# jQuery extract and display node from XML document

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm using jQuery ajax to invoke a WS-Trust service to retrieve a SAML assertion.  The response from my service includes the full WS-Trust response, and I only need the assertion from the middle of the doc.

The XML doc is:

```
    <ns3:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns10="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:ns3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/" xmlns:ns4="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns5="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200802" xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:ns7="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:ns8="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" xmlns:ns9="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity">
        <ns3:RequestedSecurityToken>
            <saml2:Assertion xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="SAML_4e367081-34ab-11e4-b48c-e062ecbc9f52" IssueInstant="2014-09-04T20:18:28.420-07:00" Version="2.0">
                <saml2:Issuer>pmdomain</saml2:Issuer>
                <saml2:Subject>
                    <saml2:NameID Format="urn:com:soa:saml:nameid-format:QualifiedName" NameQualifier="PolicyManager">Local LDAP\igoldsmith</saml2:NameID>
                    <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:sender-vouches" />
                </saml2:Subject>
                <saml2:Conditions NotOnOrAfter="2014-09-05T00:18:28.420-07:00" />
                <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-09-04T20:18:28.420-07:00">
                    <saml2:AuthnContext>
                        <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
                    </saml2:AuthnContext>
                </saml2:AuthnStatement>
                <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
    <ds:Reference URI="#SAML_4e367081-34ab-11e4-b48c-e062ecbc9f52">
    <ds:Transforms>
    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
    <ds:DigestValue>/9WRlKPTL5N2SJOYe9pSw9Coy4I=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>
    Lgxq9PdlgSTU5R6JvhFBLbGv6PZUo64DhZvlovtg/sfTSZcljHKld9XQvE5cWT4Q2O0EVhxb332O
    XBipazlw8Tluvlf5s/k2m8L9LhtR2X/kdI+HooGEyHFBFLg4cX4nKP8Mbmc+bJegOtMlFSy/Zj5y
    gZr+bNwPk0xdniblmco=
    </ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509Certificate>
    MIICATCCAWqgAwIBAgIIZ7i81vjsmF0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwQzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJ
    BgNVBAgTAkNBMQwwCgYDVQQKEwNTT0ExDDAKBgNVBAsTA1NPQTELMAkGA1UEAxMCcG0wHhcNMTQw
    NjE3MjA0ODIxWhcNMTkwNjE4MTM0NTAwWjBDMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UECBMCQ0ExDDAK
    BgNVBAoTA1NPQTEMMAoGA1UECxMDU09BMQswCQYDVQQDEwJwbTCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOB
    jQAwgYkCgYEAlyVusLGwuaFjL7nFdnvqbLVMq7T0wONpLTYDGMFwg5gEz+8gDzi7nZrtwxOe31V8
    gEz6u6KdZXfjBUNkp0JgDt8uBGWr55Rol6kYnxix5r/UwvU2gRCAl0TGwipyShqW+FmWyK/y/+R6
    5mtdD8FgmrmuBVwTGc2DxZxWJQOcqhMCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOBgQAnoiHMEdGvVa57
    o+f+o6oknHsZDz8ipWG0vLzE+Pv3ordsVLKb2iG2o8DZAG7WuECirbXiLmZQ7cV+CqBiIqm82apZ
    Aw2pnD1uTBxaakf4KRkOct/Dk8MDr/2RyOUUQcxOnW3GeJV2q6YiIiGqAPN1/7Qf9cYSSQQC7/uV
    kFPf1g==
    </ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
            </saml2:Assertion>
        </ns3:RequestedSecurityToken>
        <ns3:TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0</ns3:TokenType>
        <ns3:RequestedAttachedReference>
            <ns4:SecurityTokenReference>
                <ns4:Reference URI="#SAML_4e367081-34ab-11e4-b48c-e062ecbc9f52" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0" />
            </ns4:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ns3:RequestedAttachedReference>
        <ns3:Lifetime>
            <ns1:Created>2014-09-05T03:18:28.450Z</ns1:Created>
            <ns1:Expires>2014-09-05T07:18:28.420Z</ns1:Expires>
        </ns3:Lifetime>
    </ns3:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
```

I have 2 questions:

1 - What's the best way to extract the saml2:Assertion node into a new XML Object?

2 - What's the best way to then convert this object to a string for display in the body of my page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, updated

TODO: retain original document uppercase letters at tag

To render the contents of the tag , could utilize `saml2\\:assertion` element `outerHTML` , of `saml2:Assertions` `xml` element

Try

v2

html

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

js

```
// `ajax` method , options
$.ajax()
// `ajax` `.done()` , `success` callback
.done(function(data, status, jqxhr) {
       var xml = $(data.documentElement);
       var assertion = xml
       .children("ns3\\:requestedsecuritytoken")
       .children("saml2\\:assertion");
       // raw xml , 
       // TODO: retain original document   
       // uppercase letters at tag 
       $("textarea").val(assertion[0].outerHTML);
   });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/sqz12ma2/

Comment: I don't think this works, largely because it forces it to html which makes everything lowercase.  Plus, I need to try and display the raw XML, this just shows the contents of the tags, not the tags themselves.